# Call ActivityManagerService methods from my application

Tags: android, activity-manager, rooted-device

I've created a system application on a rooted device and was wondering: is there a way to access methods in `ActivityManagerService` from that application?

I've tried using the `ActivityManager` object but not all methods also exist in `ActivityManagerService`.

Thanx!